# Easy way to find details about a macro in bash?

Tags: bash, macros

Say I have a macro like `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` or `EEXIST`. It can be anything.

Is there an easy way to find information about them; which header file is required, what is its functionality / value and so on?

One option is to `man` the header file or function associated with it, but that is not an easy way. All opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use cscope, ctag or any similar software.
You can also use grep with -r, -R flags.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -rnw  "EXIT_SUCCESS"  /usr/include/*`. replace EXIT_SUCCESS with any words you wish.

Comment: worked for EXIT_SUCCESS . But no output for PTHREAD_MUTEX_INTIALIZER